# Display an image in a post's details corresponding to the first letter of the user's name?

Tags: python, django

In my blog app I want to display an image in the post's details. But the tricky part is that I want to display the image corresponding to the first letter of the user's first name. For example if the user's name is "Sam" I want to display the letter 'S' image. I tried to add all letters avatars in static folder.And i tried

```
 <!--code for displaying image from database--->
 {% if post.author.profile.image.url is None %}
      <img src="{% static 'images/{{letter}}.png' %}" class='logo3'/>
 {% else %}
      <img src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}" class='logo3'/>
 {% endif %}

 views.py
 def homepage(request):
 l=[]
 post= Post.objects.all().order_by('-date')
 ctr= post.count()
 print(ctr)
 for i in range(0,ctr):
    letter = post[i].author_id[0].lower()
    l.append(letter)
 return render(request,'layout.html',{'posts':post,'letter':l})

 models.py
 class Post(models.Model):
   title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   desc=models.TextField()
   date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   author=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                               to_field="username",on_delete=models.CASCADE)

 class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   image = models.ImageField(default=None,upload_to='pics')
```

In my browser if i click on inspect in img tag the src displaying is /media/None

Comment: Can you share the `Author` model?

Comment: I added my models.py in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to display images according to the user's first name is create a `div` instead of an image with rounded corners.

```
{% if post.author.profile.image %}
      <img src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}" class='logo3'/>
 {% else %}
 <div class="text-center align-center"  style="align-items:center !important;justify-content:center !important;background-color: black;width: 50px;height: 50px;border-radius: 50px">
     <p style="padding-top: 25%" >{{ post.author.username.0 }}</p>
 </div>
 {% endif %}
```

> {{ post.author.username.0 }} will give you the first letter of username

Comment: I added all letters avatars in static folder.I am trying to load that avatar if the user hasn't set the profile picture.If the user hasn't set profile picture i gave the field value as None in my model.Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you don't need to save all images in the static folder. there are simple solution to the problem..

Comment: if you wish to continue with your plan . try adding static file path and directory in the settings.py file ..official doc :- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing author by post.author object, so just do `post.author.username.0` in your template, you don't need that list of letters in context. `name.0` in Django templates corresponds to `name[0]` in Python.

Edit: set to `username` field, the alternatives are `first_name` and `last_name`.

Comment: {% if post.author.profile.image.url is None %}
              <img src="{% static 'images/{{post.author_id.0}}.png' %}" class='logo3'/>
 {% else %}
               <img src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}" class='logo3'/>
  {% endif %} is this correct?

Comment: It's an ORM, **object** relational mapper, so you just do post.author.username to access username value. post.author_id is a database representation, kind, of that relation. P.S. I edited my post as auth user has no name field.

Comment: I am not able to load images in browser under image tag it shows /media/None